# Monotonicity of the sequence $(a_n)=(\frac{\ln n}{n})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logarithms

The solution of this problem in my book is the following

"For $n\neq 1~~$  $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n \ln(n+1)}{(n+1)\ln n}<1$, so $(a_n)$ is monotone decreasing."

How can we write this inequality? I think this is wrong. How could it be the right proof?

Comment: In any manner, it is not true for $n=2$ since $\frac{a_3}{a_2}=\frac{2 \log (3)}{3 \log (2)}\approx 1.05664$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
\ln(n+1)=\ln n+\ln\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)<\ln n+\frac1n.
$$

Comment: Is the inequality $\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})<\frac{1}{n}$ true for all $n$ or $n\geq 3$? Where can i find the proof of this inequality ?

Comment: Calculus: $\ln(1+x)<x$, $x>0$.

Comment: When i use the inequality which you write how it appears the condition $n\geq 3$? I can't  see that ?

Comment: The inequality $log(1+x)<x$ is valid for all $x>0$. When you use to prove that $a_{n+1}/a_n<1$, you are lead to $1/\ln n<1$ which implies in fact that $n\ge3$. The cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ should be checked directly; it turns out that $a_1=0<a_2<a_3$.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

A simple proof is to notice that
$$
f(x)=\frac{\ln x}x,\quad f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}<0, \quad x\geq3,
$$
then $f$ **is decreasing over** $[3,\infty)$ giving
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1, \quad a_n=\frac{\ln n}n,\quad n\in [3,\infty).
$$